# IsolatedStorageFile or Windows.Storage APIs for Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, file-io, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage

I'm working on a behind-the-scenes library for Windows Phone 8. We need to use the filesystem as a crude cache. I've found that there are two APIs for Windows Phone 8 though. There is the typical IsolatedStorageFile API that was carried over from Windows Phone 7. However, there is also now the new Windows.Storage.ApplicationData set of APIs which I assume are carried from WinRT.

Which one should I use? What are the differences and why should I use one or the other? Also, how do they interact? If I create a file in IsolatedStorage, can I see it in Windows.Storage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're only targeting WP8 then, the advice I've received from Microsoft is, you should use the `Windows.Storage` APIs.

The expectation is that the others will be deprecated in future.

The guidance was actually more general. To paraphrase:

> Where there are multiple ways of doing something, if you don't need
>   backwards support, use the functionality under the "Windows"
>   namespace.

Comment: It's just a shame that the Windows.Storage APIs are significantly harder to use, especially if you're not concerned about it being asynchronous